# How to throw error when a templated class type is instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

Using SFINAE to select the right class type, I'm trying to have the base version throw an error if it gets instantiated so I know if I passed an argument which defaults to the default void version:

```
template <typename value_t_arg, typename DEFAULTVOID = void>
struct Boo
{
    //static_assert (false, ""); // IF I place the static_assert here it always fails

    Boo() {
        static_assert (false, "Assertion failed");
        // Here it only fails if this type is instantiated
    }
    
};

template <typename value_t_arg>
struct Boo<value_t_arg, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, value_t_arg>>>
{
    
};


template <typename T>
struct AnotherTemplatedClass { };

int main()
{
    Boo<int> g; // Passes because template argument is int
    Boo<float> g1; // Fails because template argument is not int
    AnotherTemplatedClass<Boo<float>> a; // Passes because constructor wasn't called
    // even though the wrong type of class was selected
}
```

I thought that by placing the static_assert inside the class declaration, but not in a function, that it would fail whenever that class was selected/instantiated. However it fails always. The way I can get it to work is by placing the static_assert inside a function, but then I have to rely on that function being called, which isn't ideal because I may instantiate that version of the class but that particular function may not be called in the code. I basically want the compiler to tell me when I've instantiated the default void version of the template class. How are you supposed to do this?

Comment: Where do I put the static_assert if I only declare it and don't define it?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44065093/4342498) in the dupe target has the work around for how to do this using `static_assert`.  It just needs a layer of abstraction to make the `false` dependent on the template parameter(s).

Comment: Reopened.  Less convinced now that it is a dupe, but the linked answer should still work for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the compiler already evaluates the `static_assert(...)` even when you don't try to use that specialization of the class.

You can achieve what you want by wrapping the `false` expression inside a boolean constant:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// ...

// Helper constant that is always false but will force the compiler to evaluate it only when the specific specialization is used
template <typename>
constexpr auto always_false = false;

template <typename value_t_arg, typename DEFAULTVOID = void>
struct Boo {
    // Now the below will only be evaluated when this specialization is called
    static_assert(always_false<value_t_arg>, "Assertion failed");
};

template <typename value_t_arg>
struct Boo<value_t_arg, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, value_t_arg>>> 
{ /* ... */ };

template <typename T>
struct AnotherTemplatedClass {
    AnotherTemplatedClass() {
        T(); // You will need to call the implicitly defined constructor to invoke the 'static_assert()'
    }
};

// ...

int main() {
    Boo<int> g;                             // OK
    // Boo<float> g1;                       // Gives an error
    // AnotherTemplatedClass<Boo<float>> a; // Gives an error
}
```

Comment: On Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community it always fails. Also, shouldn't the third line in main fail? That's what I was wanting, because the base version was instantiated.

Comment: @Zebrafish I edited the code a bit, can you see if it works now? It could be that MSVC predicts `always_false` to be `false` when a default template parameter is used. (It doesn't happen with GCC, which I used to test the above)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to perform this check is to only declare `Boo` instead of defining it. This will give you the compile-time check you want.

```
template <typename value_t_arg, typename DEFAULTVOID = void>
struct Boo;

template <typename value_t_arg>
struct Boo<value_t_arg, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<int, value_t_arg>>>
{
    
};

// insert other specializations here...
```

This way, you don't need the `static_assert()` at all because trying to instantiate the class without hitting any of the specializations will fail on account of it not actually existing.

You'll get an error along the lines of `Boo<float> does not exist`. The actual error text will depend on the compiler.

Comment: So this is kind of a workaround to get the compiler to fail to find the definition instead of working with a static_assert?

Comment: @Zebrafish It's not really a workaround. If you only want the class to exist for certain values of `T`, then this is how you express that to the compiler.

Comment: How does static_assert work when it's inside a class definition but not in a member function? Is it the same as putting static_assert in the global namespace? I don't really understand how it works or what it is. In the global namespace you can put code such as calling functions etc, but not in class definitions.

Comment: @Zebrafish It works the same way. However, if the `static_assert()` does not depend on any template parameters, it's evaluated immediately, as opposed to during instantiation. This is true both in functions and in class definitions. Maybe this will help illustrate what's going on: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xGexPWP51

Comment: Btw, `AnotherTemplatedClass<Boo<float>>` won't necessary fail (`Boo<float>` is just an incomplete type).