# Why this C++ template method is not compiled?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, visual-studio-2022, static-assert

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Test { One, Two, Three };

template<Test T> static auto some_func() {
    static_assert(false, "use specification");`
}

template<> auto some_func<Test::One>() { std::cout << "Test One" << std::endl; }

template<> auto some_func<Test::Two>() { std::cout << "Test Two" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    some_func<Test::One>();
}
```

In latest update VS2022 (17.1.2), this code stopped compile, but in previous versions build was ok.

Source.cpp(6,16): error C2338: use specification.

But if I add some condition to static_assert:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, int> && !std::is_same_v<T, int>, "use specification");
```

It will be build ok.

Why build fails first time?

And why not failing second time?
Because condition in second code, will be also False.

Comment: Because `static_assert(false)` is ill formed. Consider using `template<TestT> void some_func() = delete;`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059557/whats-the-right-way-to-call-static-assertfalse

Comment: The second time it would be dependent on the template parameter which is the correct way of writing "falsing" `static_assert`. Check [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553) and related from Raymond.

Comment: It seems more like a compiler bug that it ever compiled with either of those static asserts.

Comment: @Elliott The first case is invalid, but it doesn't require a diagnostic, so it's not a compiler bug for it to be compiled. The second case is perfectly valid.

Comment: @cigien: The second case is still invalid, since you can’t specialize type traits.

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm not seeing where in the OP's code there's a specialization of a type trait. `std::is_same_v` is being used in the `static_assert`, but it's not a specialization.

Comment: @cigien: Since you can’t specialize them, there’s no way you could make the `static_assert` valid for at least one `T` as required.

Comment: @DavisHerring Oh, I see what you mean. Yeah, that's right, it should be the same case as the `static_assert(false)` then, just much more unlikely to have the compiler diagnose that.