# push_back() function error on vector with struct data type?

Tags: c++, vector

In c++ writing header file for a vertex buffer layout.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <GL/glew.h>

struct vertexBufferElement
{
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int count;
    bool normalised;
};

class vertexBufferLayout
{
private:
    std::vector<vertexBufferElement> mElements;
public:
    vertexBufferLayout();
    template<typename T>
    void Push(int count)
    {
        static_assert(false);
    }

    template<>
    void Push<float>(int count)
    {
       //ERROR HERE
        mElements.push_back({ GL_FLOAT, count, false });
    }

    template<>
    void Push<unsigned int>(int count)
    {
       //ERROR HERE
        mElements.push_back({ GL_UNSIGNED_INT, count, false });
    }

    template<>
    void Push<unsigned char>(int count)
    {
       //ERROR HERE
        mElements.push_back({ GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, count, true });
    }
};
```

Commented where the errors are being detected.
I get error message "no instance of overloaded function"
What is causing this?

Comment: There are so many unrelated compilation errors in the shown code, that it's fairly likely that the shown code is not the real code that's experiencing the issue, and, as such, attempting to guess what the real problem is, here, would not be productive.

Comment: I believe that the use of static_assert() might be responsible for at least some of it, as when testing with T as a float I get an error. Would there be any better way for me to raise an error here? Also, for context, I'm using VS2022.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and the full text of the compiler output

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don get any sort of error when compiling or building, but my IDE still underlines it in red

Comment: So it's just an intellisense error? Ignore it, intellisense isn't a full compiler and sometimes makes mistakes. Note that `static_assert(false)` wasn't valid until c++23 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059557/whats-the-right-way-to-call-static-assertfalse

Comment: Only a full C++ compiler understand C++ source code. Your text editor, which does all this highlighting and underlining in red, is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: "Only a full C++ compiler understand C++ source code" --- this is demonstrably false.

Answer (score 1):

Using braces does not allow narrowing conversions.

When you have `mElements.push_back({ GL_FLOAT, count, false });`, the `int count` function argument is being narrowed to the `unsigned int count;`  member of `struct vertexBufferElement`, which is not allowed. So formally there is no `.push_back` that can be called with `{ GL_FLOAT, count, false }`.

GCC accepts this in a non-template context (issuing `-Wnarrowing`, it wouldn't compile with `--pedantic` or `-Werror=narrowing`), but clang does not. Likewise, other compilers and tools might have differing outputs, which is probably why you have a mismatch between your compiler and intellisense

The fix would be to fix your types (`void Push<float>(unsigned int count)`)

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with signed / unsigned mismatch in your type definition.  However, if instead of `push_back` you use `emplace_back` the compile should find the appropriate (default) constructor.

```
   template<>
    void vertexBufferLayout::Push<float>(int count)
    {
        mElements.emplace_back(GL_FLOAT, count, false);
    }

    template<>
    void vertexBufferLayout::Push<unsigned int>(int count)
    {
        mElements.emplace_back( GL_UNSIGNED_INT, count, false );
    }

    template<>
    void vertexBufferLayout::Push<unsigned char>(int count)
    {
        mElements.emplace_back(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, count, true );
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm just gonna use `mElements.push_back({ GL_FLOAT, count, false });`  as an example, the premise still hold to the other pushes:

When you put `{ GL_FLOAT, count, false }`, the compiler thinks you wanna push a vector containing three element, but they aren't the same type, so it throws an error, to make the compliler know you are pushing your own struct, just put `vertexBufferElement{ GL_FLOAT, count, false }` to make it known to the compiler that the collection of data types is a custom struct and not just a vector.

***conclusion***

```
mElements.push_back(vertexBufferElement{ GL_FLOAT, count, false });
```

that should do it

Comment: `compiler thinks you wanna push a vector containing three element`, no, `push_back` doesn't have an overload that takes a `vector` so the compiler won't interpret the initialiser list as a vector